# PowerShell command to get members of email group - Get-ADGroupMember not working

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to find the members of a group email box with PowerShell and the `Get-ADGroupMember` command but no matter what I use for the `-Identity` parameter it won't work. One thing I found odd was when using `Get-ADObject` on the email address it shows the `ObjectClass` as `user`. So that has me thinking it isn't set up as a group at all. But I'm sure that when emails are sent to the email address a group of employees gets the email. Maybe there's something strange with our AD configuration? Here's the command I run on the email address to give me all the properties:

`Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(mail=groupemail@xyz.com)"  | Get-ADUser -Properties *`

As stated I try to use the group member command but either I'm not giving it the proper identity or the object isn't a group. I've tried the GUID and the name property but neither work.

`Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive $name`

Comment: If it is a user object, then it could have a mail forward set up in the mail system. It could also have an alias that may be stored in the `ProxyAddresses` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an Exchange/Office365 Group or DistributionGroup? Then you need to install the Exchange module and use one of these commands:

For Exchange Distribution Groups:

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember
   [-Identity] <DistributionGroupMemberIdParameter>
   [-Credential <PSCredential>]
   [-DomainController <Fqdn>]
   [-IgnoreDefaultScope]
   [-ReadFromDomainController]
   [-ResultSize <Unlimited>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

For Exchange Groups:

```
Get-Group
   [[-Identity] <GroupIdParameter>]
   [-Credential <PSCredential>]
   [-DomainController <Fqdn>]
   [-Filter <String>]
   [-IgnoreDefaultScope]
   [-OrganizationalUnit <OrganizationalUnitIdParameter>]
   [-ReadFromDomainController]
   [-RecipientTypeDetails <RecipientTypeDetails[]>]
   [-ResultSize <Unlimited>]
   [-SortBy <String>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

More information can be found in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-distributiongroupmember?view=exchange-ps

Comment: I think you might be on to something. I'm just trying to get the modules installed and run some tests.